# How to add all MS packages to manifest XML

Tags: office-js

Hi can i know how to add all ms package to one manifest XML. In office JS documents describe there is separate add-ins for MS packages, What i need is put all MS packages to one Add-ins. I have already create add-ins for MS word is that possible to add other packages to that add-in.

Comment: HI Mahesh, can you clarify what you mean by 'all MS packages'? If you are looking to combine Word/Excel/PowerPoint support in one manifest you should review the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#set-the-hosts-element)

Comment: Hi thank you. yes i need to maintain one manifest file for all host(Word, Excel, PowerPoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have more than one `<Host>` element in the `<Hosts>` section of the manifest. For more information, see [Specify Office hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).